# Can't define such function in scheme programming

Tags: function, lambda, syntax-error, scheme, mit-scheme

Why do I keep getting this error???

**;Can't define name; already free: ratio**
code

```
    (define (min-ratio list)          ;;Pivot row
        (let ((r-list (ratio list)))
          (last-element (cons 0 (iter 1 (car r-list) (r-list)))))
    
          (define (ratio list)
            (if (null? (cdr list)) '()
            (let ((row (car list)))
              (cons (/ (last-element row) (list-ref row pivot-column))
                (ratio (cdr list))))))
    
          (define (iter position value list)
            (if (null? (cdr list)) '()
            (if (negative? value)
                (iter (+ position 1) (cadr list) (cdr list))
                (if (or (negative? (cadr list)) (<= vlaue (cadr list)))
                (iter (+ position 1) value (cdr list))
                (cons position (iter (+ position 1) (cadr list) (cdr list))))))))
```

Just the "ratio" function works fine, and "iter" function also works fine, but the min-ratio doesn't.
I get the error, Can't define name, ratio,  already free.

Comment: You need to move the local definitions before their use.

Comment: Are `ratio` and `iter` supposed to be internal definitions? or did you just forget to close a `)` in the last line of `min-ratio`? :) if that's the case, close it and delete the extra `)` at the end of `iter`.

Comment: Yes they are supposed to be internal definitions. I removed ) at the last line intentionally to check the iter function.    "iter" function  and "ratio" function" works fine on their own but can't use them inside min-ratio function.      No matter what name I use I always get the same error Can't define name, already free.

Comment: Move local definitions where? I didn't get it.

Comment: @SandeshShah `define` can only be the first expressions in a lambda or derived (`define`, `let`, `letrec`, ...)  and then you can have expression that actually use these. Notice that you are calling `ratio` from the value of `r-list` and that is before it exists. Also I see you are appling (calling) `r-list` in last argument of `last-element`, but it looks as if `ratio` retuns a list and not a procedure and will most likely fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
(let ((r-list (ratio list))) ...
```

Here you link `ratio` with some upper definition (maybe primitive/library one).  If the implementation does not find it defined, it can be marked as `free` and put somewhere in the global scope, hoping for you to define it later (this is implementation defined behavior).

Next, you define `ratio` inside the scope of `let`, where you alrealy referenced it and the system marked its binding as `free`.

```
(define (ratio list)...
```

It is implementation defined behavior when you use `define` inside a scope.

You should decide whether `ratio` from `let` is enclosed, or you want to define it, and, if so, put `define ratio` above let, or you can use something like `letrec (ratio ...) (r-list ...)`.